# HTML Radio Button saving first radio button value in Database

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, ajax

I'm new to work Javascript & ajax. I am creating a basic form & saving the values in the Mysql database. After hitting the submit button only first radio button value is getting saved in Database. Can anyone help me out?
**Here is my HTML Code :**

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Email:</label>
            <input type="email"  class="from-control" name="Name">
        </div>

        <label class="form-check-label">Gender</label>
        <div class="form-check-inline">
            <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="Sex" id="Sex" value="Male" />Male
            <input type=radio class="form-check-input" name="Sex" id="Sex" value="Female" /> Female
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="btn_submit">Submit</button>
            <button class="btn btn-seconday" type="button" id="btn_cancel">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**And my Javascript code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btn_save').on('click',function() {
            var Email = $('#Email').val();
            var Sex = $('#Sex').val();

            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url : "https://localhost/newCrud/test/save",
                dataType : "JSON",
                data: {Email:Email, Sex:Sex},
                success : function (data) {
                    $('[name = "Email"]').val("");
                    $('[name = "Sex"]').val("");
                }
            });
            return true;
        });
    });
</script>
```

**The Database structure**
[image: DB Structure]
**Saved data from form submission**
[image: Saved data upon form submission]

Kindly help me with my problem guys, I did my fair amount of research & couldn't find solution to my problem. Thank you for you suggestions.

Comment: If using a form you should do like `$('#formIdHere').submit(function(e){ /*run your AJAX here */ e.preventDefault(); })`, otherwise the page will reload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`id` attribute of HTML should be unique. In that case, you'll always get the first value of corresponding `id`.

Easier way to solve your problem:

```
var Sex = $('input[name="Sex"]:checked').val();
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, this solved my problem & I also understood what my problem was. I was just getting the value of Sex id & not the checked value. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

Ids must always be unique. When you do `var Sex = $('#Sex').val();` You will only ever get the first result, as it appears first in the DOM. There are plenty of different ways, but an easy option to get the values would like like...

Note: in my example female is already checked.

```js
function getRadioValue(name) {
  var inputs = Array.from(document.getElementsByName(name));
  checkedRadio = inputs.filter(x => x.checked);
  if (checkedRadio.length) {
    return checkedRadio[0].value
  }
}

console.log(getRadioValue("Sex"));
```

```html
<div class="form-check-inline">
  <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="Sex" value="Male" />Male
  <input type=radio class="form-check-input" name="Sex" value="Female" checked /> Female
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Seems like a data model issue.

You are retrieving the value from your html wherever Name equals "Sex". You have two inputs with the Name equaling "Sex". Jquery will pick the first input with the name "Sex" from the DOM. Thus you are always updating the sex to whatever the value of the first input is with the Name "sex".

That's your problem.

We can give you a proper solution if we see what your table looks like for the db instance you are inserting into.

Comment: Ok, i understood what you are trying to say. It would be a great help if you can give some suggestions. And i have added the database Structure & data images.

Comment: Right, but I couldn't give a suggestion based off your current code state. Although I answered what the problem was, I don't think this deserved a downvote given the lack of information. The "correct" answer isn't also correct, given again we didn't know your database structure. The "correct" answer modified your code incorrectly. You didn't have to change the id.

Answer (score -1):

By default one radio button should be selected.

Comment: thanks for your support. I tried that too but the problem still persists.